# ASP.NET MVC Setting dropdowns back to default value with a button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.NET MVC i created a few dropdown menu's that filter a list depending on which value you select from these dropdown menu's. I'm trying to create a buttton that sets all the dropdowns back to the standard value, essentialy "Resetting" the dropdown menu's. After this refresh i would like to submit the form automatically.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Info", "Products", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-group" }))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.productIdCode)

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.laborIdDropdown, ViewBag.LaborId as SelectList, "Lab Code", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = @"form.submit();" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.brandIdDropdown, ViewBag.BrandId as SelectList, "Brand", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = @"form.submit();" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.platformIdDropdown, ViewBag.PlatformId as SelectList, "Platform", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = @"form.submit();" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.cultureIdDropdown, ViewBag.CultureId as SelectList, "Culture", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = @"form.submit();" })
    </div>
</div>
//Button that sets all dropdowns to zero and submits form
}
```

Comment: You have to search and apply for cascading dropdown list in asp mvc

Comment: @M.Y.Mnu I'm sorry, do you maybe have some example code, i don't realy know what you mean :)

Comment: it can be help you. [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Cascading-Dependent-Country-State-City-DropDownLists-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Comment: @Timon, is there something else in the page you need to `POST` to server? If not, then just do a `GET` and retrieve default value. A parameter in the url can tell the controller to save defaults before returning.

Comment: @derloopkat Yeah i did need to post some hidden value's. After asking around here i found another solution by using JQuery. I just removed the selected attribute from all the dropdown options and posted the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from people in the comment section, and some asking around at my work i found a solution that works just fine for me. I decided to delete all the selected attributes from the dropdown options and post the form.

JQuery:

```
$('#resetButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#laborIdDropdown > option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
    $('#brandIdDropdown > option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
    $('#platformIdDropdown > option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
    $('#cultureIdDropdown > option:selected').removeAttr("selected");

    $("#filterForm").submit();
});
```